# Running an electron app, i encounter multiple MacOS errors

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

We're developing an Electron app and we're facing some MacOS errors, see :

[The image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QENGK.jpg)

The process is our electron app (music player playing lossless audio).

The app is running correclty though.

Any idea ?

Comment: Where are those errors showing up?

Comment: In the Mac OS X console.